# Sugar CRM CE edition full text search

Tags: full-text-search, sugarcrm

I cannot get SugarCRM CE to do full text search.

Does anyone know how to get this done?

Answer (score 3):

Full text search is in SugarCRM Pro, leveraging elasticsearch...

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/07/03/new-in-sugar-6-5-full-text-search-thru-elasticsearch/

Comment: Yes that is in the pro version, not the CE version I know.  How do you get it in the CE version?  coming from a country where we have a fluctuating currency paying per month in $ is not your friend $200 this month is not that much but 6 months later it is 40% than what you paid earlier.  Hence I want to stick with CE or vtiger.  Sugar is nice and easy to use but does not have search.